# How to pin a browser tab with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, pinning, browser-tab

I need to pin a browser tab to avoid the user closing the tab but still receiving notifications in a non invasive and pluginless way.

Is there a way to do so with Javascript?

Google searching yield me no results.

Comment: Preventing a user from closing a tab sounds evil. Probably something browsers would consider a security problem if it were possible. I sense an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you need this for?

Comment: @Anko Thank you for your downvote but you got me wrong. I don't want to **prevent** a user from closing the tab. I want the user to **avoid** doing it which is a different thing. the XY problem makes no sense here.

Comment: You can use [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to ask the user to verify they want to leave.

Comment: @AlperTuran I didn't downvote. What do you mean by "avoid doing it"?

Comment: @Anko Alright it's ok it was a pass-by downvote then. By "avoid doing it" I mean that the user is aware that the tab is going to be pinned rather than be closed. It's done **with their consense**. He doesn't need to close the tab because it's pinned and non invasive, so he can **avoid** closing it altogether.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I can't still ask them to pin their browser tab or do so automatically.

Comment: you can't pin tabs from JS

Comment: Pinning isn't made available to web pages. It can however be possible through extensions -- e.g. [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) for Google Chrome.